# Django (alternative to "runserver")

Tags: python, django, deployment, webserver, localhost

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy a django website without having to use a "run server" method on the command prompt. About 30 people in the company will utilize it internally, but documentation states that runserver is only for development purposes and not for production.

I've looked at MAMP, Apache, FastCGI, etc. I find myself questioning the amount of work it would require, and whether it would be recommended. My web is nothing fancy. A several files, links, Python scripts, etc.

I felt the other stack posts didn't do a great job phrasing their questions about basic "deployment methods" for django, which propagated a wide variety of answers.

**So my question is specific: "what free, internal web server application is best recommended to handle a django framework facing a traffic of about 30 users without utilizing the runserver method on command prompt?"**

Let me know how I can modify this question for better discussion.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=lightweight+wsgi+container

Comment: uWSGI + nginx on a local server, should take less than an hour to set up.

Comment: What do you mean by _internal web server application_?  Do you need to restrict access to a local intranet?

Comment: Yes I do. I don't want anyone else to access it but those within the company.

Comment: I like nginx and gunicorn.  There are lots of articles on how to set this up.  But you might first try using runserver since you have a small user base (see below).  If it gives you problems, move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING:** I know OP doesn't want to use `runserver`, I'm knowingly suggesting that he probably should because scaling is not an issue yet and there's no reason to introduce other dependencies for other reasons.

**ANSWER**
Not using runserver is a choice that depends on scale. Everything said (including django documentation warning against using `runserver` on production), your situation really isn't production set up. Django's runserver is already pretty good and can usually handle the load you intend to, and if it can't it is unlikely that any other container can help you there (it is likely that your code is buggy).

What you need is to disallow hosts other than something specific: say the machine's hostname, or just the IP. You should set [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) appropriately.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS doesn't restrict clients from accessing the application, which is what he needs.

Comment: fair point, @JohnGordon. But the question was not about security or permissions. I am hoping the OP would know the security issues involved, and I also hope OPs application is an authenticated one over a secure channel.

Comment: N.B.: `runserver` is single-threaded, single-processed, so XHR can fail without any indication.

Comment: The accepted answer is pretty lazy. It's trivial to set up gunicorn and avoids numerous issues (e.g. XHR) for very little cost. Performance if there are large static assets involved is also poor.